# R : Int vs Num Anomaly in Vector

Tags: r, floating-point, int

I was working my way through a primer on R programming and noticed a slight anomaly  :

- `x <- c(2,1,1,5)` produces a vector of type `num`
- `y <- c(1:5)` produces a vector of type `int`
- `z <- c(1.5,2.3)` produces a vector of type `num`

Why does this happen ? What is the fundamental data type in `R` : is it `int` or is it `num` ? What happens if one of the elements in the vector is a `float` , does the type of the vector become `float` or is it something else ? What happens when all the elements in the vector are `float` - why is it still `num` in that case ?

Comment: All numbers are "double"s (`typeof(2)`) unless specified otherwise (`as.integer` or `L`). `c` is a function that concatenates and coerces to highest `typeof` where in your "x" is "double".  `:` is a function that returns an "integer" vector by design. Also, "numeric" is, also, a class and returns `TRUE` for "integer"s and "double"s (see `?numeric`).

Comment: From the **Value** section of the help file (`?":"`), `For numeric arguments, a numeric vector. This will be of type integer if from is integer-valued and the result is representable in the R integer type, otherwise of type "double" (aka mode "numeric").`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two distinct issue at play:

1. In `c(2, 1, 1, 5)` you are *explicitly* creating `numeric` types.  For `integer`, you would have to use `c(2L, 1L, 1L, 5L)` as only the suffix `L` ensures creation of an `integer` type (or casting via `as.integer()` etc).  But read on ...
2. In `c(1:5)` a historical override for the `:` comes into play. Because the usage almost always involves integer sequences, this is what you get: integers.

Both forms are documented, so it is not an anomaly as your question title implies.

Comment: Hi , @DirkEddelbuettel , usually in languges like `Python` etc. `L` is reserved for `int : type long` , why is it that `R` uses `L` for type-casting to `int` . Also , which method should be preferred in practice according to you - `c()` or `c(:)` ? Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Python practice is irrelevant here.  Have a look at eg the [R Language Definition manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html).  Moreover, R only has `integer` and no distinction between different sizes of integers (ie no `long int` or `long long int`).

Comment: Thanks a ton @DirkEddelbuettel , I got it , was just wondering as to why does `R` follow a different practice in using `L` compared to other languages like Python , C/C++ , Java etc. Thanks again :)

Comment: R follows S conventions. S is is older than Python so the question might be why did Python deviate from existing practice.

Comment: @BondedDust , but don't languages like C/C++ , Java also follow the convention of using `l or L` for long ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time thinking there much more to say on this topic. R is not going to change.